# Accessing the records in the Insert Records content

Tags: typo3

I have a few "insert records" on my page with contents from the left, main and right columns each one. I would like to have them displayed with float:left in a row depending of the colum thay came from. Every one "insert records" content should be one block with border (The CSS stuff doesn't matter here).

Until now I have this:

```
lib.contentpageheader = CONTENT
lib.contentpageheader {
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos=3
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    renderObj=COA
    renderObj {
        stdWrap.wrap = <div class="separated_block"> | <div class="clearingDiv"></div></div>
        10=CONTENT
        10 {
            table=tt_content
            select.where=colPos=1
            select.orderBy=sorting
            ... something missing ...
            renderObj.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="separated_block_left"> | </div>
        }
        20=CONTENT
        20 {
            table=tt_content
            select.where=colPos=0
            select.orderBy=sorting
            ... something missing ...
            renderObj.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="separated_block_middle"> | </div>
        }
        30=CONTENT
        30 {
            table=tt_content
            select.where=colPos=2
            select.orderBy=sorting
            ... something missing ...
            renderObj.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="separated_block_right"> | </div>
        }
    }
}
```

How can I set the reference to the correct "insert records" record, so that I only get the contents, that belong to the corresponding "insert records" record? Now I'm getting all records that exist on the page ignoring the "insert records" content defined.

Something like this perhaps?

```
select.andWhere.current = 1

select.andWhere.wrap = uid=|
```

Comment: You may edit the `select.where` to specify the type of the content. But anyway, what exactly do you do with this? Seems like it could be done by just creating a TYPO3 page and create content in columns there, then render this special site completely. Not an option?

Comment: I need something that behaves like 2 dimensional structure. I need contents in left, main and right column (1st dimension) and this content should be displayed in a block (2nd dimension). I will have more of this blocks on a page.

Comment: Then maybe an extension like [multicolumn](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/multicolumn) is what you need. You can configure it in frontend rendering as well as the backend display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works even better:

```
lib.contentpageheader = CONTENT
lib.contentpageheader {
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos=3
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    renderObj=COA
    renderObj {
        stdWrap.wrap = <div class="separated_block"> | <div class="clearingDiv"></div></div>
        1=RECORDS
        1 {
            source.field = records
            tables = tt_content
            conf.tt_content.stdWrap.if {
                equals.field=colPos
                value=1
            }
            wrap = <div class="separated_block_left"> | </div>
        }
        2=RECORDS
        2 {
            source.field = records
            tables = tt_content
            conf.tt_content.stdWrap.if {
                equals.field=colPos
                value=0
            }
            wrap = <div class="separated_block_middle"> | </div>
        }
        3=RECORDS
        3 {
            source.field = records
            tables = tt_content
            conf.tt_content.stdWrap.if {
                equals.field=colPos
                value=2
            }
            wrap = <div class="separated_block_right"> | </div>
        }
    }
}
```

This way the content is grouped by the column it belongs to. Exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I'va got it this way:

```
lib.contentpageheader = CONTENT
lib.contentpageheader {
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos=3
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    renderObj=COA
    renderObj {
        stdWrap.wrap = <div class="separated_block"> | <div class="clearingDiv"></div></div>
        1=RECORDS
        1 {
            source.field = records
            tables = tt_content
            conf.tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject=CASE
            conf.tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
                key.field=colPos
                0=TEXT
                0.value = <div class="separated_block_middle"> | </div>
                1=TEXT
                1.value = <div class="separated_block_left"> | </div>
                2=TEXT
                2.value = <div class="separated_block_right"> | </div>
            }

        }
    }
}
```